# Where should I store a default list of strings in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults, plist

I have an app that stores lists of strings.

I currently have a CoreData entity for a list and for a user; a user has a relationship to many lists. A user can create more lists.

But I would like to include some default lists. Where should I store these default lists?

The options that come to mind are:

1. Prepopulate CoreData with some lists
2. Store default lists in UserDefaults
3. Store default lists in plist file
4. Explicitly create default lists in code where they are needed

What is the best way to store a default array of strings for an iOS app?

Comment: 1. SQLite, 2. UserDefaults, ... 10. Core Data.  Personally, I don't recommend using Core Data.

Comment: I like realm :)

Comment: Anywhere but in code.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://cocoacasts.com/seeding-a-core-data-persistent-store-three-strategies

Answer (score 1):

IMO there is no one-answer to your question an these really depends on your use case.

In general, if your user shall have any interaction with the default lists (manipulating, hide, delete) i would put them in your CoreData.

I assume since you have an entity for the user, you allow multiple different users to use the app on the same device? So if you would store them in the userDefaults you would also have to keep track off the modifications for each user. In general the userDefaults should only be used for "small" data, cf. [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

> The defaults system allows an app to customize its behavior to match a
>   user’s preferences. For example, you can allow users to specify their
>   preferred units of measurement or media playback speed.